# Can two parallel invocations of a static method exists in PHP?

Tags: php, web, concurrency, static, server

What will happen if same static method is called by two parallel threads?

Will it make one thread waiting or can two parallel instances of a static method exists?

Assume function don't use member variables and only use local variables.

**Example:**

```
<?php

    public class ClassName{

        public static function doStuff(){
            // Function code goes here
        }
    }

?>
```

Assume this function is called by `GET request` to the server. Then if two users send a call to the URL exactly at same time, then what will happen?

Comment: You're question is a bit abstract can you provide more information. concurrency in PHP can be interpreted in many ways

Comment: How do create concurrency? by calling the same php script twice at the same time. Or using forks with PCTNL see http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php

Comment: The lifetime of static functions and its local variables is per request and not over multiple requests. A php process is started by the webserver. The php code get's interpreted and converted into optcode. If 2 request are made 2 versions of the interpreted php code will be in the servers memory. but they do not know each others local variables. In fact they do not kwown anything about each other. you can use a database to persist variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Confirmation that PHP static variables do not persist across requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062150/confirmation-that-php-static-variables-do-not-persist-across-requests) for the information you need.

Standard PHP does not do any locking or waiting. It will just run the method and the 2 seperate request do not known of each other and they can't access each others memory(In the given case).

This is a race condition. It depends which request gets processed first. A http request is handled by a webserver and the webserver spawns a php process to process the php script.

Comment: What about threads? (2 threads from within the same process and script access the same static thing)

Comment: I know when you use threads with pctnl_fork (http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) the current process memory will be copied so the current state is copied. Then when you modify a static variable in the parent process the static variable in the forked child is not modified. For other types of concurrency read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/refs.fileprocess.process.php

A better answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274011/php-sharing-a-static-variable-between-threads

Comment: pcntl forks a new process, not a thread. I think a thread shares the static memory part but I'm not sure. Thats why I ask.

Comment: i'm sorry i used the wrong words. You're right about forking a process instead of a thread ;). again it depends on what kind of concurrency you use the manual to figure this out:  php.net/manual/en/refs.fileprocess.process.php

Comment: The same static thing? are you talking about static methods or variables?

Comment: from http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pthreads.php:

Static Members: When a new context is created ( Thread or Worker ), they are generally copied, but resources and objects with internal state are nullified (for safety reasons). This allows them to function as a kind of thread local storage.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation... :)